# error: incompatable types Login_screen cannot be converted to onDataListener

Tags: android

I am trying to call AsyncRemoteCall from my login class by passing context but it saying that

> ServiceCalls(this, "ks") is cannot be applied

.
**Login_screen**:

```
public class Login_screen extends BaseActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button submit;
    EditText email,password;
    CheckBox showpassword;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //full screen
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        email= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        password= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        showpassword= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.showpassword);
        submit= (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
        showpassword.setOnClickListener(this);
        submit.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.showpassword :
                if(showpassword.isChecked())
                {
                     password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                }
                else
                {
                  password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.submit:
                final List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email.getText().toString()));

                final String loginUrl = new AllUrls().mainhost+ "login?";
                doLogin();
                //showAlert(email.getText().toString());
                break;
        }
    }

    private LoginDO parseData(String strResponce) {

        LoginDO ld = null;
        try {

            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(strResponce);

            ld = new LoginDO();
            if ((jo.getString("status")).equalsIgnoreCase("Fail")) {
                // for error code
                ld.errormsg = jo.getString("msg");
            } else if ((jo.getString("status")).equalsIgnoreCase("Success")) {
                // success code
                ld.email = jo.getString("email");
                ld.errormsg = null;
                ld.username = jo.getString("username");
                ld.userid = jo.getString("userid");
                ld.password = password.getText().toString();
            }
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            je.printStackTrace();
        }

        return ld;
    }

    private LoginDO parseData(JSONObject jo) {

        LoginDO ld = null;
        try {

            // JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(strResponce);

            ld = new LoginDO();
            if ((jo.getString("status")).equalsIgnoreCase("Fail")) {
                // for error code
                ld.errormsg = jo.getString("msg");
            } else if ((jo.getString("status")).equalsIgnoreCase("Success")) {
                // success code
                ld.email = jo.getString("email");
                ld.errormsg = null;
                ld.username = jo.getString("username");
                ld.userid = jo.getString("userid");
                ld.password = password.getText().toString();
            }
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            je.printStackTrace();
        }

        return ld;
    }

    public void doLogin() {

        showLoader();

        RequestParams requestParams = new RequestParams();
        requestParams.url = AllUrls.mainhost + "login?";
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",email.getText().toString()));
        //nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", etPswd.getText().toString()));
        //nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dtype", "android"));
        requestParams.data = nameValuePairs;
        requestParams.typeOfRequest = AsyncRemoteCall.POST_REQUEST_DATA;
        //showAlert(requestParams.toString());
        ServiceCalls serviceCalls = new ServiceCalls(this,"ks");
        serviceCalls.execute(requestParams);
    }
}
```

**ServiceCalls class:**

```
public class ServiceCalls extends AsyncRemoteCall{

    private String tag;

    private ArrayList<Object> data;


    public ServiceCalls(OnDataListener context, String tag) {
        super(context);

        this.tag = tag;
        data =null;
    }

    public ServiceCalls(OnDataListener context, String tag, String option) {
        super(context);

        this.tag = tag;
        data =null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ResponseData result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("Resonse******", result.toString());

        if(result.error == null){

            parse(result);

        }else{

            mDataListener.onData(null, result.error);           
        }
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    public void parse(ResponseData result){


        data = new ArrayList<Object>();

        try {

            if(tag.equalsIgnoreCase("login")){

                Log.e("datadata",""+result.data);
                String str = result.data;

                mDataListener.onData(str, null);
            }
            else if(tag.equalsIgnoreCase("myAccount"))
            {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result.data);
                AccountDetilsDO ad = new AccountDetilsDO();

                if((obj.getString("status")).equalsIgnoreCase("Fail")){

                    ad.error = obj.getString("msg");

                }else if((obj.getString("status")).equalsIgnoreCase("success")){

                    ad.error = null;
                    ad.usedspace = obj.getString("usedspace");
                    ad.nooffiles = obj.getString("nooffiles");
                    ad.accountcreatedon = obj.getString("accountcreatedon");
                    ad.name =  obj.getString("name");
                }

                mDataListener.onData(ad, null);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            result.error = "Unable to connect server, please try again later";
            mDataListener.onData(null, result.error);
//          mDataListener.onData(null, result.toString());

        }

//      mDataListener.onData(null, result.error);
        data = null;
    }
}
```

**AsyncRemoteCall:**

```
public class AsyncRemoteCall extends AsyncTask<RequestParams, Void, ResponseData> {

    public static final int GET_REQUEST = 0;
    public static final int POST_REQUEST_XML = 1;
    public static final int POST_REQUEST_DATA = 2;
    public static final int PUT_REQUEST = 3;
    public final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 30*1000;
    public final int SO_TIMEOUT = 30*1000;
    OnDataListener mDataListener;

    public AsyncRemoteCall() {
    }

    public AsyncRemoteCall(OnDataListener context) {
        mDataListener = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected ResponseData doInBackground(RequestParams... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        RequestParams requestParams = params[0];
        Log.e("Request", requestParams.toString());
        if(requestParams.typeOfRequest == GET_REQUEST){
            return getData(requestParams.url);
        }else if (requestParams.typeOfRequest == POST_REQUEST_XML) {
            return postData((String) requestParams.data, requestParams.url);
        }else if (requestParams.typeOfRequest == POST_REQUEST_DATA) {
            return postRequest(requestParams.data, requestParams.url);
        }else if(requestParams.typeOfRequest == PUT_REQUEST){
            return postData((String) requestParams.data, requestParams.url);
        }

        return null;
    }


    public ResponseData getData(String url) {

        ResponseData response = new ResponseData();

        try {

            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httpClient.getParams().setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            httpClient.getParams().setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, SO_TIMEOUT);
            BasicHttpResponse httpResponse = (BasicHttpResponse) httpClient.execute(httpGet);

            int responseCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();

            if (responseCode == 200) {
                InputStream in = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
                InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(in,"utf-8");

                //
//              BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is,8);
                String read = br.readLine();

                while (read != null) {
                    // System.out.println(read);
                    data.append(read);
                    read = br.readLine();

                }
                response.data = data.toString();

            } else {

                response.error = Utils.SERVER_ERROR;
//              response.error = httpResponse.getStatusLine().toString();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            response.error = Utils.SERVER_ERROR;
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            response.error = Utils.SERVER_ERROR;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            response.error = Utils.SERVER_ERROR;
        }

        return response;
    }

    public ResponseData postData(String param, String url) {

        ResponseData response = new ResponseData();

        try {

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            Log.e("url", url);
            StringEntity content = new StringEntity(param, HTTP.UTF_8);
            content.setContentType("text/xml");
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
            httpPost.setEntity(content);

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httpClient.getParams().setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            httpClient.getParams().setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, SO_TIMEOUT);
            BasicHttpResponse httpResponse = (BasicHttpResponse) httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            int responseCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();

            if (responseCode == 200) {
                InputStream in = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
                InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(in);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);
                String read = br.readLine();

                while (read != null) {
                    // System.out.println(read);
                    data.append(read);
                    read = br.readLine();

                }
                response.data = data.toString();
            } else {

                response.error = Utils.SERVER_ERROR;
//              response.error = httpResponse.getStatusLine().toString();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            response.error = Utils.SERVER_ERROR;
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            response.error = Utils.SERVER_ERROR;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            response.error = Utils.SERVER_ERROR;
        }

        return response;
    }


    public ResponseData postRequest(Object param, String url){


        ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = (ArrayList<NameValuePair>) param;
        ResponseData response = new ResponseData();

        try {

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            Log.e("url", url);

            if(params != null)
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httpClient.getParams().setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            httpClient.getParams().setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, SO_TIMEOUT);
            BasicHttpResponse httpResponse = (BasicHttpResponse) httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            int responseCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();

            if (responseCode == 200) {
                Log.e("url 200", url);

                InputStream in = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
                InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(in);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);
                String read = br.readLine();

                while (read != null) {
                    // System.out.println(read);
                    data.append(read);
                    read = br.readLine();

                }
                response.data = data.toString();
//              Log.e("", "data.toString() "+data.toString());


            } else {

                Log.e("url error", url);

                response.error = Utils.SERVER_ERROR;
//              response.error = httpResponse.getStatusLine().toString();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            response.error = Utils.SERVER_ERROR;
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            response.error = Utils.SERVER_ERROR;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            response.error = Utils.SERVER_ERROR;
        }

        return response;
    }

    public ResponseData putData(String param, String url) {

        ResponseData response = new ResponseData();

        try {
            HttpPut httpput = new HttpPut(url);
            Log.e("url", url);
            StringEntity content = new StringEntity(param, HTTP.UTF_8);
            content.setContentType("text/xml");
            httpput.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
            httpput.setEntity(content);

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httpClient.getParams().setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            httpClient.getParams().setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, SO_TIMEOUT);
            BasicHttpResponse httpResponse = (BasicHttpResponse) httpClient.execute(httpput);
            int responseCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();

            if (responseCode == 200) {
                InputStream in = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
                InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(in);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);
                String read = br.readLine();

                while (read != null) {
                    // System.out.println(read);
                    data.append(read);
                    read = br.readLine();

                }
                response.data = data.toString();

            } else {

                response.error = Utils.SERVER_ERROR;
//              response.error = httpResponse.getStatusLine().toString();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            response.error = Utils.SERVER_ERROR;
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            response.error = Utils.SERVER_ERROR;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            response.error = Utils.SERVER_ERROR;
        }

        return response;
    }

    public interface OnDataListener {
        void onData(Object data, String error);
    }
}
```

Image of the error:

[image: image of the error]

Comment: where are you calling `new ServiceCal`?

Comment: in loginclass ServiceCalls serviceCalls = new ServiceCalls(this, "ks");
serviceCalls.execute(requestParams);

Comment: did as you said but gives error  as OnDataListener cannot be applied to android.content.Context in ServiceCalls class.

Comment: can you post more of the Login class where you call `new ServiceCalls(this, "ks");` and also point out what is it's super class.  Does it even implement `AsyncRemoteCall.OnDataListener`??

Comment: @petey yes i have now updated login class...

Comment: @Lav   Can you also add the class for `AsyncRemoteCall.OnDataListener`?

Comment: @petey No it is a context of AsncRemoteCall.

Comment: Sorry...Can you also add the class for AsyncRemoteCall.OnDataListener as part of your question so those viewing can help you with data contract that this interface requires.

Comment: @petey OnDataListener is and interface I have added.now.pls have a  look..thanks

Comment: @petey thank you so much for your help.I have got the solution..

Comment: _incompatible_ or _incomparable_?

Answer (score 0):

Change `Login_screen` to also implement `AsyncRemoteCall.OnDataListener`

```
public class Login_screen extends BaseActivity implements View.OnClickListener, AsyncRemoteCall.OnDataListener {

    // onData
    @Override
    public void onData(Object data, String error) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(error) && data != null){ 
           // use data here
        } else {
           // display error here
        }
    }
}
```